# use zlib to list directory structure of apk file in android

Tags: android, c, zlib

I am current working on an Android project.

Since the android apk file is essentially a zip file with a different file extension, is it possible to use zlib to file the directory structure of the asset folder?

The goal is to write some interfaces like opendir() and readdir() so that I can do something like:

```
DIR* dir = zip_opendir("somedirectory");
struct dirent* entry;
while (0 != (entry = zip_readdir(dir))){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "DIR", "entry: %s\n", entry->d_name);
}
```

except that all the operations take place inside a zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) (which itself uses [zlib](http://zlib.net/)) to work with zip files.  It does [all you want and more](http://www.nih.at/libzip/libzip.html).