# File hierarchy with Android native AAssetManager

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-assets

### Issue

I wonder how to make file hierarchy of assets folder in Android from native code. I'm using `AAssetManager_openDir` but `AAssetDir_getNextFileName` doesn't return any directory names so basically I have no way to dive deeper into hierarchy because I can't obtain names of subfolders. Is there any way to resolve this issue with `AAssetManager` or should I implement this in Java?

#### Example

Assets looks like

```
a/
  file1
  file2
b/
  file3
  c/
    file4
```

C++ code

```cpp
AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(env, "");
// filename is NULL since there is only folders at the root folder
const char* filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir);
AAssetDir_close(assetDir);
```

```cpp
AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(env, "a");
// filename is "file1"
const char* filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir);
// filename is "file2"
filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir);
AAssetDir_close(assetDir);
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found out that `AAssetDir_getNextFileName` implementation literally filters directories from output. 
[Link to source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/1cadc07dd1e3711fb1e57548038e3026682c5ef8/native/android/asset_manager.cpp#135)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101371/checking-if-directory-folder-exists-in-apk-via-native-code-only?

Comment: @AlexCohn No. The main difference with that question is that I don't know folders names beforehand - I want to discover it in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal in three steps, each requires some programming. The bottom line is, your assets all live in the APK file, and your app can find and read the APK file, and its format is a ZIP archive.

1. Find your APK file name.
2. Open this file for read as zip archive.
3. Iterate the zip contents for `assets/<whatever>`.

For 1), you can [use Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973314/192373) or if you must stay in c++, filter `/proc/self/fd`. You may find some system APK files (framework), but your APK will be the only one that is not system.

For 2), see *[use zlib to list directory structure of apk file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14563943/192373)*. Note that **zlib** is part of public NDK libraries.

Comment: **update:** some frameworks, e.g. Experitest, may inject additional APKs into your process.